# getOutputStream() has already been called for this response when using PrintWriter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm working on this Java Sprint 3.0 application where I'm passing data to a dataTable. Everything works fine, but every so often I see this error:

```
ERROR [[dispatcher]] Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called
```

for this response.

Here is my code:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/dataTable", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void serverSide(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

  response.setContentType("application/json");
  response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");

  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  out.print(dataTableService.viewUsers(request));
}
```

I have tried adding the following:

```
out.flush();
out.close();
return;
```

I have also tried using ***response.getOutputStream().print(dataTableService.viewUsers(request))*** and ***response.getWriter().append(dataTableService.viewUsers(request))*** instead of using a ***PrintWriter*** but nothing seems to fix it.

**EDIT:**

Here is the stacktrace:
[image]

Comment: Don't you call those in debugger?

Comment: @Naya yes I am running in debugging mode

Comment: you're kind of *misusing* spring and that could be the culprit : spring *could* pre-fill the `HttpServletResponse` if something unexpected happens. To solve your problem your method needs to **return** a `ResponseEntity` if you want to write the output yourself reliably - you also could write a proper spring view, set a model and return the view just like its supposed to be

Comment: @specialist I'm very new to spring so I'm just following an example that has been done in the application. Could you post or point me to an example as I don't really know what you're talking about. Thank you!

Comment: Can you add some more stacktrace. Is exception coming from somewhere else or from your function. One scenario to consider is viewUsers call is throwing exception and spring is trying to generate error page, but response stream was already accessed

Comment: Please take a look at RestController, or ResponseBody you don't have to write response yourself, you can just return the string and spring will do the right thing

Comment: I added a stacktrace also what do you mean by just return a string?

Answer (score 1):

The basics are:

1. headers must be written first;
2. then the content must be written using either `getOutputStream` or `getWriter`.

What still can go wrong:

- Basic errors like using both `response.getOutputStream()` and `response.getWriter()` - very unlikely here.
- Control flow:

  ```
  if (...) {
      ... redirect
      // Missing return
  }
  ... normal output
  ```
- A filter or interceptor: ordinarily unlikely; though here are annotations.

  ```
  out.flush(); // OKAY
  // Probably NOT OKAY: out.close();
  ```
- Servlet *fields* being used. The service methods should be stateless in themselves.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I have tried adding **out.flush()** only but the issue is still there. Any other suggestions?

Comment: No idea, @specializt e.a. pointed to the wrong "magic" Spring usage. An other example of spring might help.

Comment: Nothing has worked so far, do you have any other examples?

Comment: Start with an other Spring example; try returning a String, `return(dataTableService.viewUsers(request);`. The problem is that there are many variations of using spring, and I for one did not use that servlet near construct.

Comment: I tried doing that but no luck. I think the dataTable is expecting JSON so it complains when it receives just a string. I also added a stacktrace if you want to look at that

Comment: Place a new question with all the info. I am not active in spring for over a year.

Comment: No the stacktrace is interesting as I looked at it just today. A _view_ jsp is shown, so your _controller_ method should just provide a data _model_ of the table. I hope someone will be able to show a best practice example.